# finding the kernel of Fredholm integral equation of the first kind

Tags: functional-analysis, integral-equations, inverse-problems

I have the following equation: $$F(x)=\int^{a}_{b}f(x')K(x,x')dx'$$
the f(x) and F(x) are known functions and I need to find only K(x,x'). Both functions F and f are smooth, integration limits are finite. I believe this is in some sence integral equation inverse problem. Could it be solved analytically?

---

mathreadler's answer inspired me on interesting idea: let's define proper solution as one which minimize norm in Hilbert space $$K(x,x'):min_{K}||F(x)-\int^{a}_{b}f(x')K(x,x')dx'||_{L_2}$$
Looking on this as on functional $J[K(x,x')]$
$$J=\sqrt{\int(F(x)-\int^{a}_{b}f(x')K(x,x')dx')^{2}dx}$$
Minimizing this with respect to K should give some equation on K (like Lagrange equation)$$\frac{\delta J[K]}{\delta K(x,x')}=0$$   But i have no idea how to define functional derivative if function have two arguments, is it possible?

Comment: You should specify additional conditions on kernel (like represent is as rational function). Otherwise the solution is not only non-unique it is completely vague.

Answer (score 1):

The solution of the problem is far from being unique. Take, for instance
\begin{align}
F(x)&=1\\
f(x)&=1
\end{align} 
and $a=0,b=1$ as the domain of integration. All kernels
\begin{align}
K_n(x,x')'=(\alpha+1)x'^\alpha
\end{align}
with $\alpha>-1$ are solutions.

Comment: Well, this is inverse problem so that's to be expected. I guessed another solution $K(x,x')= F(x)f^{-1}(x) \delta(x-x')$ But from physical point of view i need smooth K.

Answer (score 0):

If $F$ and $f$ are well behaved enough, you can discretize it into a linear least squares system:

1. $K$ matrix : $K_{i,j} = K(x_i,x'_j)$
2. $f$ vector : $f_i = f(x'_i)$
3. $F$ vector : $F_i = F(x_i)$

$$K = \min_{K}\|F-S(K\circ (f1^T))\|_2$$ Where $S$ is a discrete sum approximating the integral, $\circ$ is Hadamard product.

$$S = \left[\begin{array}{cccccc}1&1&\cdots&1&1&1\end{array}\right]$$

We may need to add extra terms corresponding to any regularizations which may be needed.

---

Typical usual regularization terms to acquire smoothness could be $$\cases{\|D_x\text{vec}(K)\|_2\\\|D_y\text{vec}(K)\|_2}$$

Where $D_x,D_y$ are matrices doing some discrete differential wrt x and y (along rows and columns of K). Some popular ones include $[1,-1],[1,-1]^T$, $[1,0,-1],[1,0,-1]^T$ and the famous Sobel $\left[\begin{array}{ccc}1&0&-1\\2&0&-2\\1&0&-1\end{array}\right]$, $\left[\begin{array}{ccc}1&2&1\\0&0&0\\-1&-2&-1\end{array}\right]$. Although at least for the Sobel ones you would probably need some even smaller regularization filter as well.

To enforce time invariance of the kernel we can add the cost term $\|H\text{vec}(K)\|_2$ where $H = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}0&-1\\1&0\end{array}\right]$ so that each neighbouring diagonal element are encouraged to be close to each other.

---

**update** since $K$ is a matrix, we can benefit from vectorizing it. If we do that, we can write both operations above $(\cdot \circ f1^T)$ as well as multiplication by $S$ (from the left) as matrix multiplications working on the vectorization of $K$. More explanation exists at wikipedia entry on [Kronecker products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product), if you scroll down to matrix equations chapter.

The new problem to solve becomes:
$$\min_{v_K}\|F-M_SM_fv_K\|_2$$
where $v_K$ is the vectorization of $K$ (a vector), we just need to figure out what the new matrices $M_S$ and $M_f$ which do the operations mentioned above looks like.

Comment: What is the meaning of subcript "2" in the norm?

Comment: The 2-norm - solved by linear least squares. It is not sure it is the best norm to aim for, but it is probably the easiest.

Comment: Why vector $F$ substracted from resulting matrix $S*(K\circ f)$ inside the norm? Should it be some matrix instead just $F$

Comment: It is the same idea as $f(x) = g(x)$ can be solved by rewriting $f(x)-g(x)=0$ and then solving $\min\|f(x)-g(x)\|_2$, just that $g(x)$ is the whole integral expression in our case.

Comment: Oh wait you are right, it is in fact a matrix. That was not intended. I understand now it must have been confusing. In that case $S$ is a row vector of ones and we will need a circulant matrix for permuting $K$ to the right position. Or maybe instead of permuting $K$ we can enforce it to be Toeplitz by an additional regularizing term. yes that seems easier...

Comment: The matrix $S$ I used first would be sensible if we had $x$ in the upper integration limit: $\int_{b}^{x}$ but now we are only interested in the integral over the whole interval, does it make sense? Actually to be strict $S$ should of course be multiplied by $d x'$, okay?

Comment: Little summarization: i should write functional $$||F-S(K\circ f^{T})||$$ and find its minimum respect to matrix K. In your example $f^{T}$ have subcript $f^{T}_{1}$, does it have some sence? Your examples of regularization terms, how to put it in the norm?

Comment: no the one is the column vector of ones, so that the outer product $(f1^T)$  between $f$ and $1$ becomes a matrix with the column vector $f$ iterated the number of times that the number of ones in the $1$ vector has.

Comment: ok, i have $S(K_{ij})=\sum|F_{i}-\sum K_{ij}f_{j}|^{2}$ its still not clear how to minimize it with respect to matrix K. What is $\dfrac{dS}{dK_{ij}}$? Scalar by matrix derivative?

Comment: $\frac{dS}{dK_{ij}}$? What are you talking about? There is no such operator in the expression. $\circ$ is a Schur/Hadamard multiplication between two matrices of equal size. Everything else within the norm is matrix multiplications with vectors or other matrices.

Comment: but how to find minimum of this norm if not vary by $K_{ij}$?

Comment: yes we vary $K_{ij}$ but we don't need any differential operator for it. We can vectorize $K$ and write all the other operations as matrix products working on it. Hmm I should probably add that in the explanation.